# java prepared statement java.sql.SQLException: ORA-01747

Tags: java, sql, oracle

hi guys can you tell me why i get the following error by doing this query?

```
 private String updateMoneyDealsEdit = "update moneydeals set mask = substr(mask,0,?)||'1'||substr(mask,?,32), " +
"ITI=?,UTI=?,idCONTROPARTE=?,'',SDR=?,USI=?,CONFIRMATIONTIME=?,CONFIRMATIONMETHOD=?,EVENTDATE=?, " +
" CONFIRMATIONDATE=?,codicemessaggio=?,'',PARENTCODICECONTRATTO=?,'I',RESEND=1 where CODINTORD=? and CODICEMESSAGGIO=? and EVENTCODE=? and EVENTDATE=? ";
```

Comment: ORA-01747: invalid user.table.column, table.column, or columns specification. You tried to reference a column name, but the column name used is a reserved word in Oracle.

Comment: `''` (twice) and `'I'` aren't a valid set clause fragments.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So here's the update you're running formatted nicely, showing where the column names are missing:

```
update moneydeals 
    set mask = substr(mask,0,?)||'1'||substr(mask,?,32), 
        ITI=?,
        UTI=?,
        idCONTROPARTE=?,
        '',    -- Missing column name
        SDR=?,
        USI=?,
        CONFIRMATIONTIME=?,
        CONFIRMATIONMETHOD=?,
        EVENTDATE=?,
        CONFIRMATIONDATE=?,
        codicemessaggio=?,
        '',    --Missing column name
        PARENTCODICECONTRATTO=?,
        'I',   --Missing column name
        RESEND=1 
  where CODINTORD=? 
    and CODICEMESSAGGIO=? 
    and EVENTCODE=? 
    and EVENTDATE=?
```